# What do do when Pub/Sub Messaging eliminates a module's interface?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, publish-subscribe, eventaggregator

As I was implementing the "loosely-coupled" approach to messaging using Prism's EventAggregator, I came across an interesting scenario: a class which had no public interface; all of it's input and output was done via these behind-the-scenes pub/sub events. If I was to reuse this class in another project, I would look at the public interface to see what functionality it offers and what its dependencies are. But in this case there is nothing (except an event aggregator service). I would have to look inside the class to see what events it is subscribing to, and what events it publishes in order to know how it fits into its surroundings... otherwise it just sits there and does nothing.

Is this a drawback to the pub/sub pattern--lack of discover-ability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interfaces hide implementation details and that's why we use them, but at the same time they *create coupling* between components.

Pub/Sub pattern tries to *eliminate coupling*, so there is no way you can use any form of interface. Yes, it's a drawback.

Also, in your case if you want to reuse logic for Pub/Sub and other consumers using interfaces you can extract common methods to interface and then call those methods from you private Pub/Sub listeners.

Comment: You mentioned "eliminate coupling". So my class in question no longer has a hard dependency on the publisher. But in a sense, it still does: it depends on something out there to publish the appropriate event or else it will just sit there and never do anything. If I were to drop in such a loosely-coupled object into a new project and neglect to have something else publish the right event, I would be left scratching my head, "why is this object not doing anything?"

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I don't know any perfect solution in that case. Good documentation and comments will be your best friends :)

Answer (score 1):

As a dependency, doesn't it have the queues that it is listening to?  That kind of defines it's interface.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by queues; I am not using queues